# Nucleo board oled screen issue

Tags: nucleo

```
#include "mbed.h" #include "Adafruit_SSD1306.h" I2C i2c(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL); // SDA, SC Adafruit_SSD1306_I2c oled(i2c,D4,0x78,32,128); InterruptIn sw(USER_BUTTON); PwmOut motor(D7); DigitalOut led(LED1); Ticker ticker; Ticker ticker2; volatile bool switch_pressed = false; float angle = 0; enum State {SHRINK,UP,EXTEND,DOWN}; State state = SHRINK; void blink(){led=!led;}; void angleUp(){angle++;}; void angleDown(){angle--;}; void turn(PwmOut &rc,float deg){rc.pulsewidth_us(10*deg + 600);} void switch_callback() {switch_pressed=true;} void changeState() { switch(state) { case SHRINK: state = UP; ticker.attach(blink, 0.1); ticker2.attach(&angleUp, 0.01); oled.fillRect(0,18,128,12,0); oled.printf("GOING UP"); oled.display(); break; case UP: state = SHRINK; ticker.detach();ticker2.detach(); angle = 0; led = 0; oled.fillRect(0,19,128,12,0); oled.printf("SHRINK"); oled.display(); break; case EXTEND: state = DOWN; ticker.attach(blink,0.1); ticker2.attach(&angleDown, 0.01); oled.fillRect(0,19,128,12,0); oled.printf("GOING DOWN"); oled.display(); break; case DOWN: state = EXTEND; ticker.detach();ticker2.detach(); angle = 180; led = 1; oled.fillRect(0,19,128,12,0); oled.printf("EXTEND"); oled.display(); break; }} int main() { sw.fall(&switch_callback); i2c.frequency(400000); oled.begin(); while(1){ turn(motor,angle); if (state == UP){(angle>=180)?(state=DOWN,switch_pressed=1):state=UP;} if(state == DOWN){(angle<=0)?(state=UP,switch_pressed=1):state=DOWN;} if(switch_pressed){changeState();switch_pressed=false;} } }
```

My oled screen randomly turn on in the same code and the same condition. It mostly doesnt turn on. I have tried other codes and i think my code has problems. Im trying to print the state in the screen , but it doesnt work. It doesnt erase the previous state... how to i erase it and does my code have blocking codes? Need help please..